# Recent hardware errors in log

Tags: linux, hardware

I am running arch on Lenovo ideapad z510 (with windows 10) and there was always an issue with suspend. This issue is not with arch but with all distros. My system never woke up from suspend if I tried. But recently I installed kde ( was running gnome before) and suspend started working flawlessly in kde. So I thought I will try it in gnome and it worked.

But after a couple of successful suspends when I suspend my laptop for the third time it just turned off and lost all power. It would not turn on from there on. There was no power.

Since my laptop has non-removable battery I had no option giving my laptop to the service I got my laptop back in working condition in a day and the service guy told me he just reset the battery and it worked. Although he also told me that he ran some checking utility and it detected some failures on my hard-drive. That was fine with me. But this is where the problems began.

When I boot into arch now I get hardware errors. Here is the output of `sudo mcelog`

```
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 0 BANK 5 
MISC b8a0000086 ADDR ffa85fc0 
TIME 1491665960 Sat Apr  8 21:09:20 2017
MCG status:
MCi status:
Uncorrected error
MCi_MISC register valid
MCi_ADDR register valid
Processor context corrupt
MCA: corrected filtering (some unreported errors in same region)
Generic CACHE Level-2 Generic Error
STATUS ae0000000040110a MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP c09 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0 
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 60
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 1
CPU 0 BANK 7 
MISC 38a0000086 ADDR ffa87fc0 
TIME 1491665960 Sat Apr  8 21:09:20 2017
MCG status:
MCi status:
Uncorrected error
MCi_MISC register valid
MCi_ADDR register valid
Processor context corrupt
MCA: corrected filtering (some unreported errors in same region)
Generic CACHE Level-2 Generic Error
STATUS ae0000000040110a MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP c09 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0 
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 60
```

Here is the relevant output of `dmesg | grep Hardware`

```
[    0.029034] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[    0.090062] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: ae0000000040110a
[    0.090066] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR ffa85fc0 MISC b8a0000086 
[    0.090071] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1491665960 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 10
[    0.090075] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 7: ae0000000040110a
[    0.090077] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR ffa87fc0 MISC 38a0000086 
[    0.090081] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1491665960 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 10
[  313.616981] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

Output of `journalctl -b`

```
Apr 08 21:09:26 archlinux_dual kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: ae0000000040110a
Apr 08 21:09:26 archlinux_dual kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR ffa85fc0 MISC b8a0000086 
Apr 08 21:09:26 archlinux_dual kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1491665960 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 10
Apr 08 21:09:26 archlinux_dual kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 7: ae0000000040110a
Apr 08 21:09:26 archlinux_dual kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR ffa87fc0 MISC 38a0000086 
Apr 08 21:09:26 archlinux_dual kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1491665960 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 10
```

Also I am getting some other usb errors as indicated in the output of `dmesg | grep usb`

```
[    1.326141] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.326152] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.326184] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.368927] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    1.664419] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.681086] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.684415] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.937725] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.187713] usb 3-10: new low-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    7.437215] usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[    7.660503] usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    7.880482] usb 3-10: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   13.196713] usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   13.420046] usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   13.639988] usb 3-10: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   13.641687] usb 3-10: Device not responding to setup address.
[   13.848049] usb 3-10: Device not responding to setup address.
[   14.053285] usb 3-10: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[   14.166612] usb 3-10: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   14.168011] usb 3-10: Device not responding to setup address.
[   14.374619] usb 3-10: Device not responding to setup address.
[   14.579911] usb 3-10: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[   14.579989] usb usb3-port10: unable to enumerate USB device
[   14.975425] input: Lenovo EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input16
[   14.975478] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   15.035358] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
```

To be sure I also checked by installing ubuntu in little space and the errors were consistent.
How bad are these errors? I have no idea what so ever. Can anyone help me with this please?